# ios: overlap images in collection view cell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have created collection view programmatically where i have created UIImageview programmatically within collectionViewCell and images are displayed in imageview are downloaded from server asynchronously.

Code below is written in cellForItemAtIndexPath: method -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrmImgPaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

   // [imgvMainView removeFromSuperview];
    // Now the image will have been loaded and decoded and is ready to rock for the main thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        imgvMainView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34,41,177,124)];
        [cell addSubview:imgvMainView];

        [imgvMainView setImage:image];
        imgvMainView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    });
});
```

Problem is, when i scroll collection view some images are overlapped on one another. Please tell me solution to avoid it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add a link to a screenshot? Or be more descriptive when you say they overlap.

Comment: I think it happens due to image view which i have created within sync block.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because you are reusing cells (correctly) and that the previous use of the cell is still calling the previous image. You must cancel the async task when the cell goes out of view. By the way, it will make you life much easier to use AFNetworking+UIImageView to do this.

One other option is to check that there is no UIimageView in your cell before you create one.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIView *viewToRemove;
    for (UIView *view in cell.subViews) {
         if (view isKingOfClass:UIImageView){
             viewToRemove = view;
         }
    }

    [viewToRemove removeFromSuperView];

    imgvMainView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34,41,177,124)];
    [cell addSubview:imgvMainView];

    [imgvMainView setImage:image];
    imgvMainView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

});
```

Comment: But if i stop async task then my collection view will not scroll properly

Comment: No mean you need to suspend the request for the image when the cell comes out of view. If not the original request will still happen and the new one will as well and you will create two image views.

Comment: See comments I put another option for you. I wrote the code free style so please correct typos.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below line  I hope this would work what I am assuming problem of duplicate cell.

UIImageView*  imgvMainView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34,41,177,124)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgvMainView];